# ExtJS typeof element

Tags: extjs, extjs3, typeof

I want to iterate lots of elements in a loop, for example I want to pick up all grids from that loop. How can I detect if elements is a grid or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case, [getXType()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getXType) and [isXType()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-isXType)  methods of `Ext.Component` are useful.